# Google sign in button error in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio-3.0

**Situation:**

I am trying to add Google SignIn button to my project using the [Custom Google SignIn Button](https://github.com/shobhitpuri/custom-google-signin-button) library like the one shown above:

[image]

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' 
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2' 
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0' 
    compile 'com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons:google-signin:1.0.0' 
     
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1' 
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
 }
```

**Problem:**

I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons:google-signin:1.0.0]
>
> C:\Users\durga rao.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\google-signin-1.0.0.aar\4fa7da22804ff19ac92142afd0b85e2b\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16, or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Comment: what is your **question**?

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons:google-signin:1.0.0]

Comment: C:\Users\durga rao\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\google-signin-1.0.0.aar\4fa7da22804ff19ac92142afd0b85e2b\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Comment: this is the error

Comment: change `minSdkVersion` to 16 in `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

**Initial solution:**

From the tags on the question, it looks like you are using Android Studio 3.0, which uses Gradle 3.0 and above. One of the breaking changes with Gradle 3.0 plugin based on [Use the new dependency configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations)
 documentation is that the `compile` keyword has been replaced with `implementation`. So for adding [Custom Google SignIn Button](https://github.com/shobhitpuri/custom-google-signin-button) library, instead of `compile` keyword with the library use:

```
implementation 'com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons:google-signin:1.0.0'
```

**Update**:

Based on the error you mentioned, it seems in your project's `build.gradle`, your `minSdkVersion` is set to `15`. The Custom Google SignIn Button library supports `minSdkVersion` of `16` since based on [Platform Version Distribution Chart](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), 99.3% of the Android devices in the world are running API 16 and above. Changing your projects `minSdkVersion` to `16` should solve the issue. Hope this helps.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of the library. Please let me know if you face any issues. Would be happy to help.*

Comment: The library supports min API version of 16. In your `build.gradle`, you have `minSdkVersion` as 15. Changing that to 16 should solve the issue.